# A strange RED colour tab bar kind of bar flashes when I launch my app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, iphone-5

When I run my app, every time a RED tab bar kind of status bar appears when I launch the app in iPhone. Why is this happening ? Can anyone give me a solution to disable it ? I m using iOS7.

Comment: In the interface builder, Do u have any View or subclass of view with red color? Try to search in your while project "redColor"

Comment: @chosensoul did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing it with an iOS 8 build as well.